# How to especify a current key-node in xamarin with firebase?

Tags: database, firebase, xamarin

I’m working with Xamarin and FireBase, I have the next problem:

I have Users in my database and each one has a list of items. I need to retrieve the list of items of the current user, and the problem is that I don’t know how to replace the key of each user in the tree, (I just hard-wrote it). This is the snippet :

```
var products = (await client.Child("Users").Child("-MXf6T19md1UOTVvHWRU").Child("Items")
                .OnceAsync<Item>())
                .Select(f => new Item
                { . . .
```

[Here is a picture of the database tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ej7g.png)

How do I replace the **Child("-MXf6T19md1UOTVvHWRU")** by the current branch where I’m at?, taking into account that I have to access another Child next to that. Of course I have access to the Username value that is stored in preferences.

I would appreciate some enlightenment, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to retrieve the list of items of the current user, and the problem is that I don’t know how to replace the key of each user in the tree, (I just hard-wrote it).

You could use the code below to get all the items first and then get the specific item.

```
 public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .OnceAsync<User>()).Select(item => new User
          {
              Name = item.Object.Name,
              UserId = item.Object.UserId,
          }).ToList();
    }

public async Task<User> GetUser(int userId)
    {
        var allUsers = await GetAllUsers();
        await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .OnceAsync<User>();
        return allUsers.Where(a => a.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Model:

```
 public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could download the similar source code from the GitHub.
https://github.com/susairajs/Xamarin-Firebase-RealtimeDatabase